# Does App using Xcode Managed Profile expired after 1 year on App Store?

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

Hi, does Xcode Managed Profile expired after 1 year of upload? I upload it on June 2019 and renew the Developer License on February 2020. Do I need to re-upload a new version of the App to Apple Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, If you have any updates, you can upload it with your new certs unless that's unnecessary.

Comment: Since it won't expired, then I just leave it because we are not changing anything. Thanks for the reply.